# Why is an injected value sometimes null inside my custom ConstraintValidator?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, stateless-session-bean

i created a custom `ConstraintValidator` Annotation which called `APIAuth`, 
and i tried to fetch the remote user IP Address Using `@Context HttpServletRequest` , but the problem is when calling the `APIAuth` inside my Stateless , the `APIAuth` custom validator work , and it fetch the remote user ip address , but when i try to refresh the request again quickly , it throw an exception , because of `@Context HttpServletRequest` be null at this case , it need from me to wait some seconds before trying to request the `Stateless` Restful again .

my `APIAuth` Code :

APIAuth.class

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = APIAuthValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface APIAuth {
    String message() default "";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

APIAuthValidator.class

```
public class APIAuthValidator implements ConstraintValidator<APIAuth, String> {

@Context
private HttpServletRequest client;

@Override
public void initialize(APIAuth constraintAnnotation) {
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    boolean valid = "127.0.0.1".equals(client.getRemoteAddr());

    return valid;
}
```

Note: i noticed also that when i define the remote user ip address at first inside the initialize() constructor , then it cache the value and didn't update it else after some of seconds , although of refreshing requesting of `Restful Stateless API` class which contain the calling of my custom annotation many times.

Thank you,

Comment: You should be returning 'valid', not 'true'. Your code doesn't even work. It isn't likely to have anything to do with the fact that you're testing the IP address.

Comment: Hello , i edited my post , of course i return 'valid' , but i was testing to determine where is the error, i have also other uses to do with this custom validator , not to determine remote user ip only,

Comment: And do they work? Or exhibit the same behaviour? Do you really have some evidence that it is getting the IP address that is causing the malfunction?

Comment: yes the problem caused by this line : `client.getRemoteAddr()` , when the custom validator run for the first time , then `client.getRemoteAddr()` return the remote ip address correclty , but when try to recall it again and again , then the object 'client' be null , so when call the sub method `getRemoteAddr()` from it , it cause the error.. and to avoid this error , i must wait some of seconds between 2 to 5 seconds nearly before recalling the custom validator again.

Comment: So the actual problem isn't getting the IP address at all. That's just a symptom. It is that 'client' can be null. I suggest you amend your title and question accordingly.